# How to log failure to start/stop a service?

Tags: linux, audit

I want to track whether a normal user attempted to run a service.
The command for starting/stopping service is given as below:

```
service filebeat start
```

I wrote an auditd rule like below:

```
-w /usr/sbin/service -p warx -k service_attempt
```

For each time I start/stop the service, it is logging the tag (service_attempt), but the audit is not failing. Because of this I am not able to differentiate between a successfull attempt and an unsuccessful attempt to start/stop a service.

Comment: It seems like this isn't a Security Question and belongs more to a StackExchange that covers the administration of Linux Servern.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused by your question as `/var/log/auth.log` already logs denied service stop/start by users without permission.

If you want to only see the service related events and only FAILED attempts, you can run as

`$sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep service | grep FAILED`

Here is a sample output of a basicuser I just created without sudo, that then tried to run `service alsa-state restart` . The output tells you all that you may need to know, and I put the important parts (date, session, FAILED, service name, username) in bold

```
foot@BOOT:~# cat /var/log/auth.log | grep service | grep FAILED
```

> **Mar  1 21:13:24** BOOT polkitd(authority=local): Operator of
>   unix-**session:6 FAILED** to authenticate to gain authorization for
>   action org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units for
>   system-bus-name::1.255 [**systemctl start alsa-state.service**]
>   (owned by **unix-user:basicuser**)

The auth.log file will tell you all that you need to know regarding authorization failures including services and login attempts.